# How to run the test classes packaged as Jar file, using TestNG

Tags: ant, jar, testng

I have created a REST API automation frame work using TestNG and ANT. Below is my project structure.

1) 'lib' folder  (contains all the external JARs including    TestNG.jar)

2) 'bin' (contains individual class files)

3) 'build.xml'    file (contains the ANT script for running the testing using TestNG)

4) 'testng.xml' file (contains the class name to be run, referring to    the 'bin' folder)

I currently run the above setup without any issues, But I wanted to JAR the class files in the 'bin' folder and run it.
I created a JAR using all the class files in the 'bin' folder and replaced the class files with the newly created JAR. But this gives me "class not found in the classpath" exception.

the only change I did was I created a JAR using all the class files in the 'bin' folder and used it instead of the class files.

I could not figure out how to call the class file present in the JAR using my 'testng.xml' file.

below is my tesng.xml file structure,

```
<suite name="StockFunctional-Story77" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="pack01.TestStock01"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

where 'pack01' is my package and 'TestStock01' is my test class. And they are part of the JAR file.